# How to sync SDL window with terminal?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a SDL window that responds to console input. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074046/getting-terminal-input-with-sdl-window-open), and the below is what I tried so far.

```
/* g++ test.cpp -o test -lSDL2 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_render.h>

using namespace std;

const int width = 160;
const int height = 144;

static int inputThread(void *a)
{
    int in;
    cout << ">> ";
    cin >> in;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(unsigned(std::time(NULL)));

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL2",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        width * 3, height * 3,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window,
        -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(
        renderer,
        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
        width, height);

    vector<uint8_t> pixels(width * height * 4, 0);

    cout << "0 - rerender; 1 - quit the program" << endl;

    while(true)
    {
        // get input
        SDL_Thread *thread = SDL_CreateThread(inputThread, "InputThread", (void *) NULL);
        int cmd;

        if (thread == NULL) {
            printf("SDL_CreateThread failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }

        SDL_WaitThread(thread, &cmd);

        if (cmd == 0) // rerender
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            // splat down some random pixels
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    int offset = i * width * 4 + j * 4;

                    int r = std::rand() % 256;
                    int g = std::rand() % 256;
                    int b = std::rand() % 256;

                    pixels[offset] = b;
                    pixels[offset + 1] = g;
                    pixels[offset + 2] = r;
                    pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
                }
            }

            SDL_UpdateTexture(
                texture,
                NULL,
                &pixels[0],
                width * 4);

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
        else if (cmd == 1) // quit
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, the SDL window is not responsive to and it sometimes crashes. Is there any way I can improve my program so that the console and SDL window sync with each other without problems?

Comment: `SDL_WaitThread(thread, &cmd);` performs a blocking operation - this means that nothing else will happen in your code until you get input and the thread terminates, making the threading useless. You need to handle all console inputs on the separate thread, the way it is done in the question you linked

Answer (score 1):

- You have to put the thread creation out of your loop
- while in the (rendering) loop, don't wait for the thread to finish/terminate (blocking, unresponsive window)
- establish a global var, which will be read from the main thread and written by the input thread

  - therefore we have to synchronize the two threads
  - here we use an atomic var, alternatively we could use a mutex

For simplicity, the code is shortened:

```
SDL_atomic_t active;

int inputThread(void *a)
{
    int in;
    //read from cin into in
    
    //we will set the global var only if in equals to zero
    if (in == 0)
        SDL_AtomicSet(&active, 0);

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    //initial stuff
    
    SDL_AtomicSet(&active, 1);
    SDL_CreateThread(inputThread, "InputThread", (void*) NULL);

    while (SDL_AtomicGet(&active)) {
        //listen to and process sdl events
        //render
    }

    //cleanup

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference

```
/* g++ _test.cpp -o test -lSDL2 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_render.h>

using namespace std;

const int width = 160;
const int height = 144;

SDL_atomic_t active;

int inputLoop(void *a)
{
    int in = 2;

    while (in != 1)
    {
        cout << ">> ";
        cin >> in;
        SDL_AtomicSet(&active, in);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL2",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        width * 3, height * 3,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window,
        -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(
        renderer,
        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
        width, height);

    vector<uint8_t> pixels(width * height * 4, 0);
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;

    cout << "Inputs: 0 (rerender); 1 (quit the program)" << endl;
    
    SDL_AtomicSet(&active, 2);
    SDL_CreateThread(inputLoop, "InputThread", (void*) NULL);

    while (!quit)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                SDL_AtomicSet(&active, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        switch (SDL_AtomicGet(&active))
        {
        case 0: // rerender
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            // splat down some random pixels
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    int offset = i * width * 4 + j * 4;

                    int r = rand() % 256;
                    int g = rand() % 256;
                    int b = rand() % 256;

                    pixels[offset] = b;
                    pixels[offset + 1] = g;
                    pixels[offset + 2] = r;
                    pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
                }
            }

            SDL_UpdateTexture(
                texture,
                NULL,
                &pixels[0],
                width * 4);

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            SDL_AtomicSet(&active, 2);
            break;
        }
        case 1: // quit
        {
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
        default: // > 2 - nothing
            break;
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```